# How to send a variable to a text file that calling to karate feature file...?

Tags: karate

Step 01#: I am calling `'Request Date'` from json file and saving as `"RequestDate"`

```
Background: 
 json req = read('classpath:XXX/XXX/API/02_Dataset/DataSet.json')  
 * def RequestDate = get req.GameEnq.RequestDate
```

Step 02#:  I am also calling `'GameDetailsRequest'` from json file which has the field called `"RequestDate"`, I would like pass `"RequestDate"` into `"GameDetailsRequest"`.

```
Scenario: GameEnq
Given request
"""       
GameDetailsRequest          
""" 
* def GameDetailsRequest = read('classpath:XXX/XXX/API/02_Dataset/ServiceRequestData_GameEnq');
```

Note: I can able to print the `"RequestDate"` value correctly ,however i don't know how to call into `"GameDetailsRequest"`... Please assist me. Your suggestion highly appreciated

Kind Regards

Sudheer Bonam

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try `replace` for a text place holder replacement

Add a placeholder `<PLACEHOLDER_NAME>` in your text data in `GameDetailsRequest` where you want to insert `RequestDate`

eg:

```
* string GameDetailsRequest = "Game release data : <RequestDate>"
* replace GameDetailsRequest.RequestDate = "12-12-2020"
```

Now `GameDetailsRequest` will be `"Game release data : 12-12-2020"`

refer: [karate doc for replace](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace)